# How to add a custom field to apache solr?

Tags: 8, search

How do you create your own solr field using Drupal 8's search api?

Answer (score 7):

1) Copy /modules/contrib/search_api/src/Plugin/search_api/processor/AddURL.php into your own custom module at /src/Plugin/search_api/processor

2) Rename and rework (see below)

3) Add your extra field to the index at /admin/config/search/search-api/index/myindex/fields

4) Enable the processor on your search_api index

5) Reindex content and verify in solr that your new custom field is indexed.

http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/#/mysolrcore/schema-browser?field=sm_mymodule_content_type, click on "Load Term Info" to see data loaded in.

Here's an example:

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\search_api\processor;

use Drupal\search_api\Datasource\DatasourceInterface;
use Drupal\search_api\Item\ItemInterface;
use Drupal\search_api\Processor\ProcessorPluginBase;
use Drupal\search_api\Processor\ProcessorProperty;

/**
 * Adds a custom type filter to the indexed data.
 *
 * @SearchApiProcessor(
 *   id = "mycustom_field",
 *   label = @Translation("Custom Field"),
 *   description = @Translation("Add a custom field to search index"),
 *   stages = {
 *     "add_properties" = 0,
 *   },
 *   locked = true,
 *   hidden = false,
 * )
 */
class CustomField extends ProcessorPluginBase {

  /**
   * machine name of the processor.
   * @var string
   */
  protected $processor_id = 'mycustom_field';

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getPropertyDefinitions(DatasourceInterface $datasource = NULL) {
    $properties = array();

    if (!$datasource) {
      $definition = array(
        'label' => $this->t('Custom Field'),
        'description' => $this->t('custom field'),
        'type' => 'string',
        'processor_id' => $this->getPluginId(),
      );
      $properties[$this->processor_id] = new ProcessorProperty($definition);
    }

    return $properties;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function addFieldValues(ItemInterface $item) {
    $entity = $item->getOriginalObject()->getValue();

    $custom_field = '';

    // Use $entity to get custom field.


    $fields = $this->getFieldsHelper()
      ->filterForPropertyPath($item->getFields(), NULL, $this->processor_id);
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
      $field->addValue($custom_field);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you expect the processor to show up on /admin/config/search/search-api/index/{index_name}/processors, you must change `hidden = true` to `hidden = false` in the plugin annotation.

Comment: Do this always create a multi-valued field? I mean what is the change needed to create a `ss` instead of a `sm` field?

Comment: I had lots of trouble getting this to work; I also read https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/search-api/developer-documentation/create-custom-fields-using-a-custom-processor. I created https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr/issues/3146018 to explain the issue I ran into and my workaround.