# Indexing image url in search api drupal 8

Tags: 8, media, uri, search

How to index the absolute image url instead of image uri in search api drupal 8.

Image field formatter renders the image url but there is no option to index the url part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that should be available as a field.

[image]

If your field name is "field_image", you would select "field_image:entity:uri".  I think that would give you "public://path-to-file-in-public-directory.jpg"

You could add a [custom field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/218130/45409) to your index in a custom module at src/Plugin/search_api/processor:

In this way, you can add any sort of custom value that's not available by default in the fields provided.